# Yii Query conversion from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have working queries that have been tested in PHPmyAdmin, i want to implement them in the controller file, so it runs every time stock is updated

This is the PHP

```
$sql = 'UPDATE shadestock,
SET MinQ_Alert = 1 
WHERE qty < Min_Quantity';
```

And the original MySQL code

```
UPDATE `shadestock`
SET MinQ_Alert = 1
WHERE qty < Min_Quantity
```

I have used the query builder http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

but to no avail, the query just doesn't execute and if i put a statement telling it to execute it give a CdbException.

All i need the above code to do is check all rows in the table and in the Min_Alert column set the value to 1(YES) where the qty < Min_Quantity.

Comment: Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update("shade_stock", ["MinQ_Alert" => 1], "qty < Min_Quantity")
```